# put three div next to each other but left and right divs must repeat to edge of browser

Tags: html, css

http://dentaliran.ir/back-final-mata.gif

above image is for header of a website,
as you can see it's 3 part
left
center
right

how can we put this three part in 3 div but left and right part must repeated to the edge of browser?

for fixed width we can put three die next to each other like this:

```
#wrapper
{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;

}
#left
{
     background:url(pics/left.jpg) repeat-x;
     height:192px;
     width:100px;
     float:left;
}
#center
{
    background:url(pics/center.gif) no-repeat;
    height:178px;
    width:800px;
    float:left;

}
#right
{
     background:url(pics/right.jpg) repeat-x;
     height:192px;
     width:100px;
     float:left;
}
```

but what about when left and right haven't fixed width and must be repeated unlimited?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/6GE3x/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 100px;
}

#wrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#left, #center, #right {
    display: table-cell;
}

#center {
    width: 200px;
}

#left {
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/MARPAT_woodland_pattern.jpg/50px-MARPAT_woodland_pattern.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#center {
    background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Q11tJy3fAhA/UUnEu5Q3BtI/AAAAAAAAFEQ/TPBl0Sd5V9I/s1600/dark-brown-wood-pattern.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

#right {
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/29/MARPAT_woodland_pattern.jpg/50px-MARPAT_woodland_pattern.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: the result is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

use min-width instead of width

Answer (score 0):

Some absolute positioning would sort it.

You could apply the left background image repeated to the body tag

the right background, I'd put it in a div, position absolute to the top,

```
body {
    background:url(pics/left.jpg) repeat-x;
}

#right{
    background:url(pics/right.jpg) repeat-x;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -50%;
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```